# Reading a file into a multidimensional array with Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

If I have a text file like this:

```
Hello World
How are you?
Bye World
```

How would I read it into a multidimensional array like this:

```
[["Hello", "World"],
 ["How", "are", "you?"],
 ["Bye" "World"]]
```

I have tried:

```
textFile = open("textFile.txt")
lines = textFile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = lines.split(" ")
```

But it just returns:

```
["Hello World\n", "How are you?\n", "Bye World"]
```

How do I read the file into a multidimensional array?

Comment: `lines = map(str.split, open('testFile.txt'))`

Comment: @falsetru interesting. it is fastest I think. Post an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and `str.split`:

```
with open("textFile.txt") as textFile:
    lines = [line.split() for line in textFile]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> with open("textFile.txt") as textFile:
        lines = [line.split() for line in textFile]
...     
>>> lines
[['Hello', 'World'], ['How', 'are', 'you?'], ['Bye', 'World']]
```

[`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is
>   also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `str.split()` with no arguments takes care of all type of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with *the unbound method* [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> map(str.split, open('testFile.txt'))
[['Hello', 'World'], ['How', 'are', 'you?'], ['Bye', 'World']]
```

In Python 3.x, you have to use `list(map(str.split, ...))` to get a list because [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in Python 3.x return an iterator instead of a list.

Comment: Is it should be `map(lambda line: line.split, open('testFile.txt'))`, when I do `str.splite` it says str not object.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, You don't need `lambda`, because `str.split` is unbound method. `'a b c'.split()` is like `str.split('a b c')`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, `str.splite`? Is it a typo? Or, did you overwrite `str`?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer:

```
with open("textFile.txt") as textFile:
    lines = [line.strip().split() for line in textFile]
```

This will remove '\n' if it is appended to the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to use `strip` to remove the `\n`:

```
myArray = []
textFile = open("textFile.txt")
lines = textFile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    myArray.append(line.split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

A good answer would be :

```
def read_text(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        line_array = file.read().splitlines()
        cell_array = []
        for line in line_array:
            cell_array.append(line.split())
        print(cell_array)
```

Which is optimized for readability.

But python syntax let's us use less code:

```
def read_text(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        line_array = file.read().splitlines()
        cell_array = [line.split() for line in line_array]
        print(cell_array)
```

**And also python let's us do it only in one line!!**

```
def read_text(path):
    print([[item for item in line.split()] for line in open(path)])
```