# Convert list of tuples of mixed data types into all string

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have this list;

```
List=[(1, 'John', 129L, 37L), (2, 'Tom', 231L, 23L)]
```

I want to convert it to look like this;

```
OutputList = [('1', 'John', '129', '37'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23')]
```

All the data type in the list will be turned into string. I tried `[str(i) for i in List]` but it did not turn out right. What is the proper way to solve this?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: "did not turn out right" is not a helpful description of the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [nested list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) ([generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) inside):

```
>>> lst = [(1, 'John', 129L, 37L), (2, 'Tom', 231L, 23L)]
>>> [tuple(str(x) for x in xs) for xs in lst]
[('1', 'John', '129', '37'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23')]
```

or using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) in place of the generator expression:

```
>>> [tuple(map(str, xs)) for xs in lst]
[('1', 'John', '129', '37'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23')]
```

The above list comprehensions are similar to following nested for loop:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for xs in lst:
...     temp = []
...     for x in xs:
...         temp.append(str(x))
...     result.append(tuple(temp))
...
>>> result
[('1', 'John', '129', '37'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23')]
```

Comment: using your answer I just tried nested map (just for learning purpose)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, `lambda i: str(i)` in your answer can be replaced with `str`.

Comment: yes I tried it works, what is the key trick behind it when to use lambda or when I can avoid.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Is the last comment a question?

Comment: Yes I had doubt. I remember you told me sometime back in time here [I could find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056125/reading-a-file-into-a-multidimensional-array-with-python#comment28164227_19056245) I read again now clear to me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this:

```
>>> lst
[(1, 'John', 129L, 37L), (2, 'Tom', 231L, 23L)]
>>> map(lambda x: tuple(map(lambda i: str(i), x)), lst)
[('1', 'John', '129', '37'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23')]
```

Edit:  Replaced `lambda i: str(i)` to just `str` in inner map:

```
>>> map(lambda t: tuple(map(str, t)), lst)
[('1', 'John', '129', '37'), ('2', 'Tom', '231', '23')]
```